# How to get continuous position of view that is constantly moving in circular direction in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, position

I am trying to get position of a view that is moving in a circular direction. I am able to get the starting position but I don't have a clue about how to get this position as view changes its position.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let mainCircleDiameter: CGFloat = 280
    let outerCircleDiameter: CGFloat = 320
    
    @State private var angle: Angle = .degrees(0)
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
            GeometryReader { geo in
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 10)
                        .frame(width: mainCircleDiameter)
                    
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 25)
                        .offset(y: outerCircleDiameter / 2)
                        .rotationEffect(angle)
                        .onAppear {
                            withAnimation(
                                .linear(duration: 6)
                                .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                                    angle.degrees = 360
                            }
                        }
                }
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
            }
            .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the position of that view continuously?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you provide how exactly you are moving the view

Comment: @narek.sv, the view is moving in a circle direction as you can see in the code. It gets an initial angle of '0', which becomes 360 in duration of 6 seconds as soon as view appears. I am then using rotationEffect(angle) to move the view in circular direction.

Comment: By View, I mean the Circle with width 25.

Comment: @MuhammadAbubakar: If my mind serves `.linear` simply means that at time `0<= t <= 6` the completion percentage will be `t/6` and therefore your angle would be `360*t/6` or equivalently `60*t`. At time `t > 6` you can replace `t` with `t mod 6`

Comment: @Bafforasta, I need value of position i.e x & y values.

Comment: @MuhammadAbubakar: What you call 0 degrees is actually 270 degrees in xy frame of reference (in a mathematical sense). 

In your case your circle will be `x: outerCircleDiameter/2 * cos(60*t + 270)` and `y: outerCircleDiameter/2 * sin(60*t + 270)` with respect to the center of the circular trajectory

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the position of the circle is being determined by the animation. That's fine for presentation purposes, but when you need to be able to read the angle and use it elsewhere, you need to change the way the data is being sourced.

One way would be to use a `Timer` to update the angle:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let mainCircleDiameter: CGFloat = 280
    let outerCircleDiameter: CGFloat = 320

    @State private var angle: Angle = .degrees(0)
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1 / 60.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
            VStack {
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 10)
                            .frame(width: mainCircleDiameter)

                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: 25)
                            .offset(y: outerCircleDiameter / 2)
                            .rotationEffect(angle)
                    }
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                    .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                        angle += .degrees(1)
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 400, height: 400)

                Text("Angle: \(Int(angle.degrees) % 360)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You said you wanted to know the "position" of the moving circle. If you know its current angle then you can calculate its position. For example, you could use a computed property to deliver its relative position from the centre of the circle. Like this:

```swift
var position: CGPoint {
    CGPoint(
        x: (-outerCircleDiameter / 2) * sin(angle.radians),
        y: (outerCircleDiameter / 2) * cos(angle.radians)
    )
}
```